# C# Inequality Operator: Checking against multiple values

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I want to check if an User Input is a specific number ( a 1 or a 9), if not I want him to reenter his input.
I am trying the following code:

```
int playerchoice = 0;
            while ((Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out playerchoice) == false) || (playerchoice != (1 | 9)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input could not be accepted, please enter a valid number");
            };
```

The issue seems to be with the second part of the check: No matter if I use (playerchoice != (1 | 9)) or (playerchoice != (1 & 9)), it always either checks against the 1 or the 9, not both.

What can I do to fix this? Am I using the wrong operator?

Edit: I know I could just check against each value individually,  but as I plan on eventually having a lot of options this seems quite impractical.

Comment: This is bitwise expressions at play, `1 | 9` means *OR the bits of 1 and 9 together*, and since 9 already has the 1-bit, the result is 9. `1 & 9` means *AND the bits of 1 and 9 together*, which means only the bits in common stays, which means the result is 1.

Comment: In other words, you want to make two comparisons: `(playerChoice != 1 && playerChoice != 9)` (Or the C# 9 pattern - I don't know  offhand how precedence works there...)

Comment: I got the expression for the pattern matching wrong, I haven't used it much yet, apparently this works but I'm not sure it is better than just spelling it out like @JonSkeet did: `playerchoice is (not 1) and (not 9)`. There may be better ways of writing it as well. Seems `playerchoice is not (1 or 9)` also works.

Comment: The wrong expression I provided in my now deleted comment: `playerchoice is not 1 or 9` is apparently identical to `playerchoice is (not 1) or 9`, and if it is 9, then it also matches `not 1`, so this got compiled and optimized down to just `playerchoice is not 1`, according to the IL.

Comment: Another option is to create a collection for the values like `var correctValues = new HashSet<int> { 1, 9 }` and then do `!correctValues.Contains(playerchoice)` and you'd just add new value to the `HashSet` as needed.

Comment: Don't test against `true` or `false` - just use `!` on the `Int32.TryParse`. And perhaps read the C# language reference on what `|` and `&` do.

Comment: _I know I could just check against each value individually, but as I plan on eventually having a lot of options this seems quite impractical_ - you can add an `IsValidInput` method, then, which can return the meaning of the input as an `out` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest sulotion is to check against each of the values individually, but if have a lot of numbers to check against, another sulotion is to use a `HashSet`. Here's a simple example:

```
class Program {
    private static readonly HashSet<int> nums = new HashSet<int> { 1, 9, ... };
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (nums.Contains(i)) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```